# Which CloudKit Database do App Store Reviwers see?

Tags: ios

When doing App Review, does Apple's staff access CloudKit's development or production database?

Comment: Do they test production or development version of your app? ;)

Comment: Touché. I take it you mean, if they're reviewing a release build, they get the production database?

Comment: Yes - they test the same binary that is then published to the store, and from CloudKit quick start we know that - „An app in development can access either the development or the production environment. **However, an app sold on the store can access only the production environment**.” [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EditingSchemesUsingCloudKitDashboard/EditingSchemesUsingCloudKitDashboard.html)